# Unit Test a private field which is behavior relevant

Tags: java, testing, junit, mocking

first of all: I found few solutions for my problem but the "newest" one was from 2014 and used reflections so I hope I could maybe find some more advanced solutions for my question.

Thats the case and its about `migrateUser` and `canAdd`. This is an example class to make my question easily visible.

```
public class UserInterfaceImpl implements UserInterface {

    private final List<T> accountList = new LinkedList<>();
    private final AccountInterface accountInterface;
    private boolean bonusReceived = false;

    public UserInterfaceImpl(AccountInterface accountInterface) {
        this.accountInterface = accountInterface;
    }

    public void migrateUser(AccountMergerInterface accountMerger, UserInterface oldUser) {
        boolean success = accountMerger.performChange(this, oldUser);
        if (success && !bonusReceived) {
            //addBonus
            accountInterface.deposit(1);
            bonusReceived = false;
        }
    }

    public boolean canAdd() {
        return accountList > 0;
    }

    public AccountInterface getAccount() {
        return accountInterface;
    }
}
```

The `migrateUser` method changes the some account Data which is not relevant for my test because I would test it separately of course (should be like that what I read so far).

So I wonder, how can I see if the behavior of that class changes the `bonusReceived` correctly? Without using reflections and do it as sophisticated as possible?

My first attempt was that:

```
@Test
public void testMigrateUser() {
    AccountMergerInterface test = mock(AccountMergerInterface.class);

    // define return value for method getUniqueId()
    when(test.performChange()).thenReturn(true);
}
```

But now I cannot continue. The rule should be in my example to have no getter and setter! The class should be like my example.

I don't know how to:

1. set `bonusReceived` to false **before** `migrateUser` is executed that `accountInterface.deposit(1);` is **not** executed
2. see if `bonusReceived` **will be set** to false if the `if()` continue is *true*.
3. Same questions for the List: how can I access the private field of List, add an Object so that the return value is *true* or *false*. Or should I "simulate" a List and if yes, how can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is refactoring your code an option ?

Comment: One option is to unit test the externally visible behavior of the class. This carries the benefit that your unit tests remain valid even as the private implementation changes, which is one of the points to unit tests. If you really want to test aspects of the private implementation, one approach is to provide package-protected members, and place the unit test in the same package.

Comment: Timothoys answer is spot on. You do not **want** that your unit tests know about this private boolean thing. You only want to test that given "this" input "that result shows up. How that is implemented should not be part of your test. Or do you intend to change your test every time you refactor production code?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unit tests check *public observable behavior*.

There is no point in verifying *internal state* of an object since this may change to support other behavior. You don't want to change your unit test in that case...

So mock the `AccountMergerInterface`  (as you already did) and the `AccountInterface` and verify that your class under test calls the methods on them in the right order with the right parameters:

```
@Rule 
public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule(); 
@Mock
private AccountMergerInterface accountMergerInterface;
@Mock
private AccountInterface accountInterface;
@Test
public void testMigrateUser() {
    // arrange
    when(test.performChange()).thenReturn(true);
    // act
    new UserInterfaceImpl(accountInterface).migrateUser(accountMergerInterface);
    // assert
   InOrder inOrder Mockito.inOrder(accountMergerInterface, accountInterface);
   inOrder.verify(accountMergerInterface).deposit(1);
   inOrder.verify(accountInterface).whatEverToCallNext();
}
```

> Same questions for the List:

There is currently no code dealing with the list in `UserInterfaceImpl`.
You cannot verify behavior which is not there...

Comment: Ah okay that means that if I have the method public void addElement(T element){ list.add(element) } I am allowed to use that in my @Test method to verify if canAdd() is working properly? If so I understood the rule in my book wrong :) I thought the convention is that I should always  only use the method I test without accessing any other of the class I test to prevent side effects errors. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: If that method is part of the classes  API then you should use it, since it is part of the classes behavior that you verify. You should avoid adding code to you class whch is only needed for testing. The only valid exception is a (package private) *getter* for a *dependency* that is instantiated within the class under test and cannot be changed to be injected.